# Is this the correct syntax for styling single elements in a Table?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is make a table and style the table header in a different way than the table data. so I wrote this code:

```
<table class="class-name">
     <tr>
          <th> Table Header </th>
     </tr>
...
</table>
```

so I decided to implement CSS code externally by creating a file and referencing it in the head section of the html document and wrote this code:

```
th.class-name, th
{
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: Gray;

}
```

Is this the correct syntax? I thought it was supposed to be something like:

```
th.class-name
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: Gray;
    
    }
```

But when I try to write it like that it doesn't work.

Comment: try `table.class-name tr th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the CSS is targeting `th.class-name` which is all `th` with the class `class-name` and because you have the comma, it is also targeting all `th`.

The second example is targeting `th.class-name` which is all `th` with the class `class-name`.

For the HTML you provided, you could use a variety of options:

`th`

`table th`

and many more.

Answer (score 1):

`th.class-name` is the syntax for a `<th>` elment with the class name `class-name`. Your `<th>` element has no class (you assigned the class to the `<table>` element, not the `<th>`) therefore it ignores the CSS for `th.class-name`. Adding the extra `th` selector also makes it valid for all `<th>` elements, that is why the first example works.

Comment: Thank you! I had trouble understanding the classes and now I get it!